# Bootstrap dropdown on toggle change background color

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have this code:

```
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle buttonForProfile" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="./php/signout.php">Sign out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I added some css and now it looks like this:

[image]

When I click on it, the background changes back to default:

[image]

How do I change that gray background when the dropdown is toggled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #dropdownMenuButton:focus {
   background-color: //color;
 }
```

PS: btn-secondary gives it the grey color, you don't need it if you're customizing the color.